# Error fatal signal 11

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, java-native-interface

I am doing an application with native code.
I have a bug, that sometimes produces this error in the logcat, but not produces runtime error:

```
06-27 18:14:47.526: A/libc(32659): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 592 (Thread-1045)
```

I have read at internet and it says that could be produces for native code, in concret for the bad acess to memory.

Someone knows somethig?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a seg fault.  Its occurring at address 0, which means you're dereferencing a NULL pointer.  Its occuring in libc, so its certainly happening in native code, which may be through you calling it directly or through the framework calling it.  That's all you can tell from that one line.

Comment: Thanks. It starts when I use the same native code from two diferents activitys. Is there any way to clean the native memory? Maybe it is produced by some interference..

Comment: Its not that easy.  You're trying to access a NULL pointer, which means some data structure you expect to be valid isn't.  You're going to have to actually debug the code I'm afraid.

Comment: FWIW, the line doesn't indicate that the error is happening in libc; rather, the "libc" tag means that the code doing the logging is in libc.  See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/linker/debugger.cpp line 138.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error with the same address. After "googeling" for days i was stucked. 
Today  i found the solution (in my case): i use win 8 x64  with eclipse Juno. The problem was solved when i have disabled the UAC from windows. 
Both the adb.exe and eclipse (in my case) were runned in admin mode. 
Hope will help someone.